# DeviceIOControl API not found in UWP C++ application

Tags: windows, uwp, ioctl, desktop-bridge, wdm

I want to Convert my existing app code which interact with Kernel mode driver(WDM driver). For IOCTL i’m using DeviceIoControl APIs.

For porting my app to UWP i’m using this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/how-to-use-existing-cpp-code-in-a-universal-windows-platform-app?view=vs-2017 .

After applying changes in project properties as mentioned in link, i’m getting error as DeviceIoControl identifier not found. That’s issue i’m facing. Is there any sample app/API available instead of DeviceIoControl?

Comment: Is this going to be a Store application or sideloaded UWP?

Comment: @BenVoigt..Yes.It's going to be store application.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, we added [DeviceIoControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-apis#apis-from-api-ms-win-core-io-l1-1-0dll) to the allow list in RS5.  You need to get a HANDLE to the device first, and that will require two changes

- Call CreateFileFromApp instead of CreateFile
- The device being opened needs to grant access to app container.  If
  you own the driver and it is a custom device interface, you can use
  a custom cap.

If you are accessing an in box defined device interface, you can’t get a direct HANDLE to the device. If your MSR access driver is a pnp driver you can use the guidance above.

Comment: Ya i saw with latest kits. DeviceIoControl is allowed. But for that we need a driver handler. As you suggested i'm using CreateFileFromApp for that but getting error 4252(ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED_IN_APPCONTAINER). My driver is like Toater driver (not having physical device). Let me know if you have any sample code usage of CreateFileFromApp/CreateFile2 for Toaster kind of device.

Comment: `CreateFileFromApp` won't work; for now can you try using [`CreateDeviceAccessInstance` instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/deviceaccess/nf-deviceaccess-createdeviceaccessinstance)?

Comment: While using CreateDeviceAccessInstance, in GetResult(IID_IDeviceIoControl, (VOID **)&ioctl) i'm getting Invalid argument (hResult E_INVALIDARG One or more arguments are invalid). What should be first argument of "GetResult" api?

Comment: After giving actual device name instead of Symbolic link, i'm getting access denied  error for GetResult API.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `DeviceIOControl` from UWP apps. You can see the list of supported [Win32 and COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-and-com-for-uwp-apps) APIs and this is not one of them. UWP apps have a more restricted security model to make it harder to use as a malware vector, so you can't interact with arbitrary kernel mode drivers.

There is a specific scenario where you can enable a custom capability and use [Windows.Devices.Custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.custom) APIs. See [CustomCapability sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomCapability). This is intended for hardware support aps generally. See [Hardware Support App (HSA): Steps for Driver Developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devapps/hardware-support-app--hsa--steps-for-driver-developers).

Comment: For Software driver also that sample can be used. As my driver is not Device Driver. For that also same APIs should work?

Comment: Well, you can use UWP and unrestricted Win32 in the same program, but it won't be accepted by the store.  So you're definitely giving OP the correct guidance

Comment: I have analyzed the code at CustomCapability sample. But that is more related to a specific device. I don’t have a device and I need to execute rdmsr(__readmsr) and wrmsr to read and write MSRs. Do I need to use enable a custom capability OR are there any other UWP compliant methods to access MSRs?

Comment: @Chuck Walbourn..Now I'm using now  CustomCapability sample.I've modified driver and application with proper permission. Still i'm getting error in opening my device. Access  is Denied. While debugging i found error is when API "FromIdAsync" is getting called. Want to know reason behind that.

Comment: See link above, in particular "Reserving a custom capability"

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Xavier Xie, CreateFileFromApp and CreateFile2FromApp are available in later Win10 releases to get brokered device handles from app container.  This is probably the easiest approach if you already have a lot of Win32 code that you want to port.

Device access also has UWP version in [Windows.Devices.Custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.custom).  This also brokers the device handle but encapsulates it into a CustomDevice object which you can use to do IO control to your device.

Note: in both cases, the device handle gets brokered (ie. created in the runtime broker in medium IL, and marshaled into the app container) if the app its self doesn't have permissions to directly open the device.  What this means is that the device interface will still need to be ACL'ed or otherwise granted access such that the app can open it.

The most current best way to grant access to an app to access your device is through a [custom capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devapps/hardware-support-app--hsa--steps-for-driver-developers).  The Device Access Broker will check the interface's DEVPKEY_DeviceInterface_UnrestrictedAppCapabilities key for the app's PFN.  In the legacy flow, Device Access will check  DEVPKEY_DeviceContainer_PrivilegedPackageFamilyNames.